# Every $n-$ dimensional manifold is homemorphic to $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: differential-geometry

This may seem like a really silly question based on the definition of a manifold (because every manifold is locally like Euclidean space), but can someone give me a counterexample where an $n-$dim manifold is not homemorphic to $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: The $n$-sphere.

Comment: Is it true then that $M^n \cong \Bbb R^{n+1} - \{ p \}$?

Comment: @jip: No, this is true only for spheres, because of , e.g., stereographic projection. The torus is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2 -pt.$

Comment: @PassingBy, lol worth a shot generalizing.

Comment: @jip: It is a good idea to generalize and learn from getting it wrong; I have gotten way too many wrong, but experimentation and guessing are a good way to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any n-manifold that needs more than one chart is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. Generalizing  the answers above, by topology:

1)No compact n-manifold is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, since $\mathbb R^n$ is not compact

2) No disconnected manifold ,

3) No manifold with non-trivial n-th fundamental group or non-trivial homology;
these manifolds  are not just not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ , but they are not even homotopically equivalent (which is much weaker than homeomorphism) to $\mathbb R^n$

---

4) Fill in your favorite topological property of $\mathbb R^n$ and then any manifold not satisfying that property is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: So I am guessing $S^n$ fails the first one.

Comment: @jip: Exactly. And the 3rd too.

Answer (score 3):

A disjoint union of two copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

An $n$-dimensional sphere $S^n$.

An $n$-dimensional torus $T^n$.

Answer (score 2):

The unit circle is not homeomorphic to the line.

Comment: Oh right, the easiest example.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there are many obstructions for an $n$-manifold to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. (If there weren't, manifold topology would be really boring!) I think all of the ones that have been described are homotopy invariants coming from [algebraic topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_topology): $\mathbb{R}^n$ is [contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space), so any homotopy invariant is trivial on it. Hence if you have an $n$-manifold where any such invariant is nontrivial then it cannot even be homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n$, let alone homeomorphic. For example:

- the set $\pi_0$ of connected components distinguishes $\mathbb{R}^n$ from two disjoint copies $\mathbb{R}^n \sqcup \mathbb{R}^n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (arguably the simplest counterexample);
- the [fundamental group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group) $\pi_1$ distinguishes $\mathbb{R}^n$ from the $n$-torus $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ (for example).
- the higher [homotopy groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group) $\pi_k$ distinguish $\mathbb{R}^n$ from the $n$-sphere $S^n$ (for example).
- the [homology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_%28mathematics%29) groups $H_k$ or [cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology) groups $H^k$ also distinguish $\mathbb{R}^n$ from the $n$-sphere $S^n$, and more generally from any compact $n$-manifold.

(Compactness, which is a priori a topological condition, is actually an algebro-topological condition on $n$-manifolds as well, provided that you know $n$: for a connected $n$-manifold $X$, it's equivalent to $H^n(X, \mathbb{F}_2)$ not vanishing.)

All of these invariants vanish when an $n$-manifold $X$ is contractible, or equivalently when it is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, it is *still* not true that a contractible $n$-manifold is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$! The [Whitehead manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold) is a famous counterexample here for $n = 3$.

For positive results along these lines, see the [Poincaré conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture), [Mostow rigidity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostow_rigidity_theorem), and the [Borel conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_conjecture).